# Oracle 12c/SQL: does "insert into table a (select from table b where x)" use temp tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, temp-tables

We are wondering why our temp space is always reducing temporarily but a lot (and released again).
The command in question has the form

```
insert into table a (fields) select fields from table b where condition
```

Does Oracle use a temp table for commands like these?
Manuals say "temp tables are only used for sorting", but we don't used a "order by" clause here.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a temp table. However, if table b is a complex view it could be the case.

Answer (score 0):

TEMP tablespace is also used for other operations such as "direct path read" and as overflow for PGA memory intensive operations.

dba_hist_active_sess_history.temp_space_allocated (11g+) - shows SQL with high TEMP consumption

dba_hist_tbspc_space_usage - shows periods of high temp consumption

DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY.pga_allocated can be used to show which SQL use the most PGA.

Comment: In the meantime we indeed identified the command m.a. as really being the "guilty" one -
so at the end you say command of this form - while handling some million records to - use temp space. Thank you, Roger!